# How to use shift in /bin/sh ? shift: can't shift that many

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I am understanding how to use `shift` statement in the shell (`sh`) scripts. But, I am getting the error `shift: can't shift that many`
Part of the script where `shift` is used is given below:

```
#!/bin/sh
.
.
.

test_sample(){
 while :; do
  case "${1-}" in 
  .
  .

  a)
   shift
     case "${1-}" in
     cmd1)
      echo "Test"
     cmd2)
      echo "Test 2"
     .
     .
     esac ;;

  b)
   shift
     case "${1-}" in
     cmd3)
      echo "Test 3"
     cmd4)
      echo "Test 4"
     .
     .
     esac ;;
   
  esac
  shift
done

return 0      
}

test_sample "$@"
```

The script will be invoked from command-line with command line arguments. The expected behavior is `./test_sample.sh a cmd2` should give the output "Test 2".

Can anyone please let me know how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing here.

Comment: You are using `shift` in your case block, and then using it again, all this in an infinite loop. But can you provide a full code sample showing the problem, with the arguments you use ?

Comment: You seem to have an infinite loop that keeps shifting, even after there are no arguments left.  Unfortunately you say nothing about what you are trying to do or how you invoke your code.

Comment: as a side note, you should avoid using `test` as a function name, as it may conflict with the command of the same name and lead to very unexpected bugs

Comment: Hello @Uriel & Kusalananda, I have edited my OP with more info ad hopefully it is somewhat clear now. Otherwise please let me know

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda how can I check if no arguments are left and stop shifting if there are no additional arguments?

Comment: Use the `$#` variable. If it has the value zero, then there are no more arguments. Use `break` to exit the loop.

Comment: Hello @glennjackman, can you please show how and where to use `$#` above? in `test_sample "$#"` statement?

Comment: `while :; do if (( $# == 0 )); then break; fi; ...; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you have a loop that never terminates but instead tries to use `shift` even when there are no more arguments to shift.

Corrected code:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

main () {
        while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; do
                case $1 in
                        a)
                                case $2 in
                                        cmd1) echo 'Test 1' ;;
                                        cmd2) echo 'Test 2' ;;
                                        *) echo 'error a' >&2; exit 1
                                esac ;;
                        b)
                                case $2 in
                                        cmd3) echo 'Test 3' ;;
                                        cmd4) echo 'Test 4' ;;
                                        *) echo 'error b' >&2; exit 1
                                esac ;;

                        *) echo 'error' >&2; exit 1
                esac

                shift 2
        done
}

main "$@"
```

Note that the outer loop now tests whether there are any arguments left, and terminates if there aren't any.

I also only do a single `shift` of two arguments at the end of the loop, and use `$1` to detect the `a` or `b`, and then `$2` to detect the argument after.

The following code changes the above to use proper option parsing using `getopts`.  This changes your `a` and `b` so that we now expect `-a` and `-b` instead, each with an option-argument:

```bash
$ ./script -a cmd1 -bcmd3
Test 1
Test 3
```

```bash
#!/bin/sh

main () {
        OPTIND=1

        while getopts a:b: opt; do
                case $opt in
                        a)
                                case $OPTARG in
                                        cmd1) echo 'Test 1' ;;
                                        cmd2) echo 'Test 2' ;;
                                        *) echo 'error a' >&2; exit 1
                                esac ;;
                        b)
                                case $OPTARG in
                                        cmd3) echo 'Test 3' ;;
                                        cmd4) echo 'Test 4' ;;
                                        *) echo 'error b' >&2; exit 1
                                esac ;;

                        *) echo 'error' >&2; exit 1
                esac
        done
}

main "$@"
```